# Is it possible to maintain added Attributes on a ListItem while posting back?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, attributes, postback, listitem

I am generating ListItems for a CheckBoxList control in ASP, but when I do something like the following:

```
...
Dim newListItem As ListItem = New ListItem("RoleName")
newListItem.Attributes.Add("style", "color:blue;")
CheckBoxListControlToFill.Items.Add(newListItem)
...
```

"RoleName" is maintained from post back to post back, but my style tag is dropped after the first post back.  If I want to keep any attribute like this, do I need to re-add it every post back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes will be lost after a postback. The question below links to a [blog post](http://blogs.delta-n.nl/dev/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=61dbd0ca-5c9f-4060-9d13-94177fe070a7&ID=85) that contains code that will persist attributes to the view state, the code is in c# though -

[ListItems attributes in a DropDownList are lost on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313447/listitems-attributes-in-a-dropdownlist-are-lost-on-postback)