# How to save a third value in each ListItem of an ASP.NET dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net

Each ListItem in an ASP.NET has a value property and a text property. I need to have a third value saved also. My hack is to concatenate a special separator and the third value to the Value property.
But using FindByValue method makes this cumbersome.

Is there a better way to save the third value or a good way to use FindByValue. (I can't use FindByText). I wish there was a Tag property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a binded `DropDownList`, defined with the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties, there's not really a good way to save the third value on the `DropDownList` itself. You could save it separately tho.

If you're defining your `DropDownList` through the markup, you could try defining it as a custom attribute:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDummy" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="x" Value="y" ThirdValue="z" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

For retrieving it, you could use FindByValue and get the `ThirdValue` attribute from the ListItem:

```
ListItem item = ddlDummy.Items.FindByValue("y");
string value = item.Attributes["ThirdValue"];
```

However, weirdly, if you generate the items dynamically, the attributes will not be persisted:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem("x", "y");
        item.Attributes.Add("ThirdValue", "z");
        ddlDummy.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

If this is your case, you could take a look at this question that gives a work arround:

[ListItems attributes in a DropDownList are lost on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313447/listitems-attributes-in-a-dropdownlist-are-lost-on-postback)