# "Multiple inheritance" - methods for a derived base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, inheritance

**Summary**

In VB.NET (.NET 4.0), is it possible to derive `ListControl` and have the same method available for `RadioButtonList`, `CheckBoxList`, `DropDownList`?

*Edit: I have added the C# tag in the hope that C# will have a solution that can also be used with VB.NET. If that is not the case I will remove the tag to stop confusion.*

**Details**

Using this [exceptionally helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3099755/930393), I have written a class (derived from `DropDownList`) to allow me to persist attributes on individual `.Item` objects across post-backs.

I would like to extend this functionality to the `RadioButtonList` and `CheckBoxList` controls, but I can't figure out if this is possible - and if it is, how to do it.

This would have been fairly straight forward in C++, as it has the ability for multiple inheritance - but I'm stuck here.

The obvious solution is to replicate the `DropDownList` derived class, but I would prefer it if the code wasn't repeated 3 times.

Can anybody point me in the right direction, as I'm having a real brain-fart here?

---

This is roughly what I already have for the derived `DropDownList` control, and it works perfectly...

```
<ToolboxData("<{0}:DropDownListPersistant runat=""server""></{0}:DropDownListPersistant>"), DefaultProperty("Text")> _
Public Class DropDownListPersistant
  Inherits DropDownList

  Protected Overrides Function SaveViewState() As Object
    ...
  End Function

  Protected Overrides Sub LoadViewState(ByVal savedState As Object)
    ...
  End Sub
End Class
```

This is what I tried, but it does **not** work, because obviously `DropDownListPersistant` is no longer derived from `DropDownList`...

```
Public Class ListControlPersistant
  Inherits ListControl

  Protected Overrides Function SaveViewState() As Object
    ...
  End Function

  Protected Overrides Sub LoadViewState(ByVal savedState As Object)
    ...
  End Sub
End Class

<ToolboxData("<{0}:DropDownListPersistant runat=""server""></{0}:DropDownListPersistant>"), DefaultProperty("Text")> _
Public Class DropDownListPersistant
  Inherits ListControlPersistant
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something with the extension method. I think you can have emulate multiple inheritance with extension methods like below.

http://coding.abel.nu/2012/05/emulating-multiple-inheritance-with-extension-methods/

Comment: Thanks Jalpesh, I will look into that... seems like it's more of a hack than a proper solution, but it also seems like that might be the only way.  Will get back to you

Comment: Multiple inheritance directly not possible with Microsoft.NET because of various reason that's why You should have some kind of hack. I have written a complete blog post why multiple inheritance is not supported here-http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2012/06/why-c-does-not-support-multiple.html