# Bind multiple column values to checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

```
<asp:Panel ID="plOffice" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Width="200px" Height="80px" CssClass="TB">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkOffice" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Height="80px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkOffice_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</asp:Panel>
```

```vb
Dim DsStatus As New DataSet
D.FillDataSet(DsStatus, "select * from Z_AppStatusMaster")
ChkStatus.DataSource = DsStatus
ChkStatus.DataTextField = "StatusDescription"
ChkStatus.DataValueField = "AppStatusID"
ChkStatus.DataBind()
```

Note: Bind multiple column values to checkboxlist. I need to bind more column values to checkboxlist.
I am already using `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`...

Comment: Loop the items in the dataset and add `ListItems` manually.

Comment: I want to bind more column values from my database. I alerady used DataTextField,DataValueField.do you know other property that can store another column value?

Comment: `ChkStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = A + B, Value = A + B });`

Answer (score 0):

You can **customize the SQL Query** so it delivers exactly what you want to display:

```
D.FillDataSet(DsStatus, "select AppStatusID, StatusDescription + ' - ' + SomeOtherField as CustomDescription from Z_AppStatusMaster")
ChkStatus.DataSource = DsStatus
ChkStatus.DataTextField = "CustomDescription"
ChkStatus.DataValueField = "AppStatusID"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you will need to create a class that inherits from the DropDownList and then overrides the SaveViewState, LoadViewState and RenderContents subroutines.

I cannot post our code as it is proprietary, but we do this and then add additional values to each item by adding an attribute. As an example:

```
   For Each dr In ds.Tables(1).Rows
        cbo.Items.Add(New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(dr("NAME"), dr("VALUE")))

        cbo.Items(cbo.Items.Count - 1).Attributes.Add("GROUP", dr("GROUP"))

    Next
```

This article will get you most of the way there:
http://www.techinfocorner.com/post/Adding-Attributes-and-Keeping-DropDownList-ListItems-Attributes-on-Post-back-in-ASPNET

And this link should help as well: [ListItems attributes in a DropDownList are lost on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313447/listitems-attributes-in-a-dropdownlist-are-lost-on-postback)